# Using AND & OR when joining tables in hql

Tags: join, hql, amazon-athena

I'm trying to join two tables in athena, selecting rows from table1 which have either their start or end coordinates in table2. I can't seem to get my code to work though. All I want is a count of entries. The coordinates in the first table are stored as strings, hence my casting them as real.
The error I'm getting is query timeout.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dotnov2016 
JOIN uniquetripcoords
ON (round(CAST(dotnov2016.startlat AS REAL),3) = uniquetripcoords.lat and round(CAST(dotnov2016.startlon AS REAL),3) = uniquetripcoords.lon)
OR (round(CAST(dotnov2016.endlat AS REAL),3) = uniquetripcoords.lat and round(CAST(dotnov2016.endlon AS REAL),3) = uniquetripcoords.lon)
```

Here's a snapshot of relevant columns from the tables.

dotnov2016:
[image]

And here's uniquetripcoords:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Sure, what would be the best way for me to do that? Screenshot or type the values into my original question?

Comment: Enter the sample data in tabular form as text.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm sorry I wasn't sure how to add the information in tabular form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause of the join mismatch is caused by the type cast you provided in your sample query.

First you cast the value from string to REAL. In Athena "REAL" is not an accepted column type, I tested your scenario and it was necessary to change the column to double to actually create the table, so please check that the table column type actually matched the casted type.

The second issue was the round-function. In you sample data, both tables have a larger precision than 3 decimals. So by rounding only the values in one table, you actually corrupt your data.

I uses the following simplified version of your query to test the statement:

```
select * from t2
join t1
ON ( CAST(t1.lat AS DOUBLE) = CAST(t2.lat AS DOUBLE) and CAST(t1.lon AS DOUBLE) = CAST(t2.lon AS DOUBLE) )
OR ( CAST(t1.lat AS DOUBLE) = CAST(t2.lat AS DOUBLE) and CAST(t1.lon AS DOUBLE) = CAST(t2.lon AS DOUBLE) );
```

Comment: I tried casting as double, and rounding both to 3, and it throws up an error 
'no viable alternative at input '(round(cast(dotnov2016.startlat as double),3) = (round(uniquetripcoords.lat,3) and round(cast(dotnov2016.startlon as double),3) = (round(uniquetripcoords.lon,3))\nor (round(cast(dotnov2016.endlat as double),3) = (round(uniquetripcoords.lat,3) and round(cast(dotnov2016.endlon as double),3) = (round(uniquetripcoords.lon,3))\ngroup' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: fb509a1a-dcba-11e6-b9b9-cfdfa0ad4def)'

Comment: Your issue seems to be related to the source data or table definition, I used string columns for "lat" and "lon" and another table with double as column type. Both tables are derived from json files uploaded to S3. Than both casts get correctly executed and I get an response (with the round applied to it).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try comparing to values from `uniquetripcoords` which have also been rounded to 3 decimal places?  Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dotnov2016 t1
INNER JOIN uniquetripcoords t2
    ON (ROUND(CAST(t1.startlat AS REAL), 3) = ROUND(t2.lat, 3) AND
        ROUND(CAST(t1.startlon AS REAL), 3) = ROUND(t2.lon, 3))
    OR
       (ROUND(CAST(t1.endlat AS REAL), 3) = ROUND(t2.lat, 3) AND
        ROUND(CAST(t1.endlon AS REAL), 3) = ROUND(t2.lon, 3))
```

If this still results in no matching records, then you can lower the threshold of precision for a matching latitude or longitude value.  Do this by changing the rounding precision to something lower, e.g. two decimal places or even matching whole numbers.